# Can $\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{\log(\frac{4}{b}\sqrt{a^2-x^2})}e^{ikx}dx$ be found in closed form?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to see if it is worth pursuing to try to calculate the following integral analytically:

\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{\log(\frac{4}{b}\sqrt{a^2 -x^2})}e^{ikx}dx\end{align}

If the singularities are problematic, these can be removed by introducing a regularisation parameter $\epsilon > 0.25$:

\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{\log(\frac{4}{b}\sqrt{a^2+\epsilon^2b^2 -x^2})}e^{ikx}dx
\end{align}

Comment: This integral screams for a substitution of the form $x=a\cos t$. But $($non-trivial$)$ integrands containing expressions like $\cos(\cos x)$ usually yield [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function#Definitions) functions as results. However, I'm afraid that, in this particular case, not even these will suffice.

Comment: Agreed. I did attempt this substitution but I couldn't really get beyond that due to the logarithm in the denominator...

Comment: it MAY be possible to evaluate the integral with the techniques @Lucian suggested, but i  really need more time to have a closer look later

Comment: I don't believe this is possible (even for $k=0$).

Comment: @O.L after a having a closer look, i think you are right\

Comment: Please edit this question to include additional context: where did this integral arise? Why is it worth considering, out of the infinite number of integrals one could write?